# div col-md-4 content too large

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

hey guys sorry but im a noob in the forum and also too in bootstrap i got this problem (i thinking in spanish i have no idea how to describe it) lets try it.

i got three col-md-4 (12col) the first col is only text, the other two are images these have an height auto, en because the first one seems to be larger then the height of the rest, is showing a gap under the images.

```css
body {
            overflow-x: hidden;
        }
        
        .container-fluid {
            padding-left: 0;
            padding-right: 0;
        }
        
        .carousel {
            padding-right: 0;
            padding-left: 0;
            text-shadow: 2px 2px 4px #000000;
        }
        
        .col-md-4,
        .col-4,
        .col-xs-8,
        .col-md-8,
        .col-lg-8,
        .col-5 {
            padding-right: 0;
            padding-left: 0;
        }
        
        .icons {
            background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgb(182, 15, 204), rgb(255, 0, 128));
            color: white;
            display: block;
            /* overflow: auto; */
            word-wrap: break-word;
        }
        
        .icons_icon {
            /* padding-top: 50px; */
            display: inline-block;
            vertical-align: middle;
            font-size: 3vw;
        }
        
        .fruta {
            width: 350px;
        }
        
        .img-fluid {
            position: relative;
            background-image: cover;
        }
        
          .circulo {
            /* width: 119px; */
            margin-left: 50px;
            margin-top: 20px;
            height: 6vw;
        }
        
          .color1 {
            background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgb(15, 176, 204), rgb(255, 0, 128));
            color: white;
        }
        
        .color2 {
            background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgb(204, 176, 15), rgb(255, 0, 242));
            color: white;
        }
        
        .color3 {
            background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgb(130, 2, 250), rgb(255, 0, 128));
            color: white;
        }
        
        .Noticias_profile h4 {
            margin: 30px;
            padding-left: 20px;
            bottom: 0;
            overflow-wrap: break-word;
        }
        
        .Noticias_profile {
            height: 2vw;
        }
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <!--ESTILOS CSS BOOTSTRAP-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!--ESTILOS CSS PROPIOS-->
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"> -->
    <!-- font aweseom -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/css/all.css">
</head>

<body>

    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 Noticias_profile">

                <div class="container">


                    <div class="row color1">
                        <img class="img-fluid rounded-circle circulo" src="https://alabamaburgerfactory.com/index/img/4anioservicio.jpg" data-holder-rendered="true">
                        <h4>Años de servicio<br>Javier Gonzáles<br>Contáctologo</h4>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row color2">
                        <img class="img-fluid rounded-circle circulo" src="https://alabamaburgerfactory.com/index/img/5reciennacido.jpg" data-holder-rendered="true">
                        <h4>Recien Nacidos<br>Macarena Alfaro<br>Febrero</h4>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row color3">
                        <img class="img-fluid rounded-circle circulo" src="https://alabamaburgerfactory.com/index/img/6cumple.jpg" data-holder-rendered="true">
                        <h4>Cumpleaños<br>Renata Gonzáles<br>Contáctologo</h4>
                    </div>
                </div>


            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 ">
                <img class="img-fluid" src="https://alabamaburgerfactory.com/index/img/7beneficios.png">
                <div class="titulo">
                    <p>Beneficios.</p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 ">
                <img class="img-fluid" src="https://alabamaburgerfactory.com/index/img/8formulario-beneficio.jpg">
                <div class="titulo">
                    <p>Formluario de Beneficios</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MrrN3.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0iYwR.jpg)

Comment: forgot i upload the site here
[link](https://alabamaburgerfactory.com/index/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make Height:100% as show below for img-fluid class,

```
.img-fluid {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Note: you can remove margin-left & margin-right for .row class as its creating little overlapping of images.

Answer (score 0):

I saw your website. You have added rows again in the `col-md-4` which is applying margin
Try this below code.It'll get solved

```
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 Noticias_profile">


                <div class="d-flex color1">
                    <img class="img-fluid rounded-circle circulo" src="./img/4anioservicio.jpg" data-holder-rendered="true">
                    <h4>Años de servicio<br>Javier Gonzáles<br>Contáctologo</h4>
                </div>

                <div class="d-flex color2">
                    <img class="img-fluid rounded-circle circulo" src="./img/5reciennacido.jpg" data-holder-rendered="true">
                    <h4>Recien Nacidos<br>Macarena Alfaro<br>Febrero</h4>
                </div>

                <div class="d-flex color3">
                    <img class="img-fluid rounded-circle circulo" src="./img/6cumple.jpg" data-holder-rendered="true">
                    <h4>Cumpleaños<br>Renata Gonzáles<br>Contáctologo</h4>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 ">
                <img class="img-fluid" src="./img/7beneficios.png">
                <div class="titulo">
                    <p>Beneficios.</p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 ">
                <img class="img-fluid" src="./img/8formulario-beneficio.jpg">
                <div class="titulo">
                    <p>Formluario de Beneficios</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Just remove the `row` and add `d-flex` class in place of it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers, it solve the problem but now on responsive the icons are not looking good, also any good recomendation about bootstrap course ? i did
CSS - The Complete Guide (incl. Flexbox, Grid & Sass) , and from scratch to know i learn tons but i dont feel ready for big proyects yet.

[link] https://i.stack.imgur.com/h5XyZ.jpg
  [link] https://i.stack.imgur.com/byOzr.jpg